# multiple statements to select distinct rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm completely new to SQL.  I have a table with multiple rows for the same ID (Alpha_code).

I want to query this table to provide only 1 row for each Alpha_code.

I need it to first select the newest row if rows have been added on different (contact_date).

I have found the statement below does this no problem.

```
SELECT m.*
    FROM (SELECT Alpha_code, max(Contact_date) AS MaxDate FROM contactsNTH GROUP BY Alpha_code)  
    AS mm INNER JOIN contactsNTH AS m ON (mm.MaxDate = m.Contact_Date) AND (mm.Alpha_code = m.Alpha_code)
```

However there are other multiple rows that were entered on the same (contact_date).  I'm not sure how to add more code to then only show 1 of the multiple rows remaining.

I've tried the Select Distinct statement but it didn't work.

Any assistance would be appreciated.  If I can answer this myself in the meantime I'll post the answer

thanks, shaun

This thread is close to what I'm asking but I find the answer confusing.

How To Select Distinct Row Based On Multiple Fields 4

Comment: Simple by using an inner query. See my answer with demo

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your schema as given here :- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e6ff/2

You can use the following query

```
SELECT c1.Alpha_code,c1.Contct_date from contactsNTH as c1
LEFT JOIN 
contactsNTH as c2 
ON
c1.Alpha_code = c2.Alpha_code 
AND
(c1.Contct_date > c2.Contct_date) group by c1.Alpha_code
```

This query doesn't works in Standard SQL because it says, "a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to non aggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the GROUP BY clause"

Try using this query

```
SELECT c1.Alpha_code,MAX(c1.Contct_date) as contact_date from contactsNTH as c1
LEFT JOIN 
contactsNTH as c2 
ON
c1.Alpha_code = c2.Alpha_code 
AND
(c1.Contct_date > c2.Contct_date) group by c1.Alpha_code
```

both will provide the same result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e6ff/4

Comment: thanks for your advise Deepika, I'm getting the following error when I try this query out on SQL server:

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'contacts.contact_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: SELECT c1.alpha_code,c1.contact_date 
from contacts as c1

LEFT JOIN 
contacts as c2 
ON
c1.alpha_code = c2.alpha_code 
AND
(c1.contact_date > c2.contact_date) group by c1.alpha_code

Comment: Hi, that is because you may be using standard SQL, which says " a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to non aggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: try using this query                                               SELECT c1.Alpha_code,MAX(c1.Contct_date) as contact_date from contactsNTH as c1
LEFT JOIN 
contactsNTH as c2 
ON
c1.Alpha_code = c2.Alpha_code 
AND
(c1.Contct_date > c2.Contct_date) group by c1.Alpha_code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using inner query. [**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80047/5)

```
SELECT Alpha_code, Contact_date AS MaxDate FROM contactsNTH AS t WHERE
Contact_date = (SELECT MAX(Contact_date) FROM contactsNTH
WHERE Alpha_code=t.Alpha_code)
```

I wrote a query using simply group by and having maximum date but it failed Then I wrote these words in google `select group by having max` and found the result. this is an example guide for you to get such problems fixed quickly